# What are the differences between Amazon Redshift and the new AWS Glue datawarehousing services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, data-warehouse

I am confused about these two services. It looks that they are offering the same service. Probably the only difference is that the Glue catalog can contain a wider range of data sources. Does it mean that AWS Glue can replace Redshift?

Comment: AWS Glue isn't a data warehouse. Glue is an ETL service. If anything you might want to compare Redshift to Athena, but Glue is not a similar service at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess that I have formulated my question wrongly. Yes, Glue is an ETL service while Redshift is a data warehouse service, however, according to my understanding, Redshift should have an ETL capability, otherwise, how can we store the data into the warehouse without a proper layer of ETL operations?! Moreover, the data warehouse, as a storage, is nothing but a database with less keys and no normalization constraints. The key factor in data warehousing is first the ETL process and the large storage place.

Comment: Your assumption that Redshift has ETL capability, and that any database would have an ETL layer is wrong. Redshift is an analytics database. If you need to ETL your data to get it into Redshift you would use another service like Glue. You need to think of AWS services as building blocks that you piece together to create the solution you need, instead of looking to a single service to provide everything.

Comment: So, if we ignore the storage part, let me re-formulate the question to be: What are the differences between the ETL opertions that I can do in Redshift when compared to the Glue's?

Comment: @Mark B, I have not assumed that any database has an ETL layer, rather I assumed that Redshift is a database with an ETL layer (a complete data warehouse solution not just the "large database" part of it). Is that wronge?

Comment: Yes that is wrong. Redshift is not a "complete data warehouse solution" it is simply an analytics database engine. AWS Glue + S3 + Lambda + Redshift might be considered a "complete data warehouse solution". Like I said, you have to piece together the Amazon service building blocks to create your "complete solution". AWS provides you the tools to build your solutions to fit your exact needs, it rarely provides a complete solution with a single service.

Comment: @Mark B, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 8):

The Comment is right , These two services are not same AWS Glue is ETL Service while AWS Redshift is Data Warehousing service.

According to [AWS Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) :

Amazon Redshift is a fast, fully managed, petabyte-scale **data warehouse service** that makes it simple and cost-effective to efficiently analyze all your data using your existing business intelligence tools. It allows you to run complex analytic queries against petabytes of structured data, using sophisticated query optimization, columnar storage on high-performance local disks, and massively parallel query execution.

According to [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/what-is-glue.html) :

AWS Glue is a **fully managed ETL (extract, transform, and load) service** that makes it simple and cost-effective to categorize your data, clean it, enrich it, and move it reliably between various data stores

You can Refer the Documentation Provided by AWS for Details but essentially these are totally different services.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess that I have formulated my question wrongly. Yes, Glue is an ETL service while Redshift is a data warehouse service, however, according to my understanding, Redshift should have an ETL capability, otherwise, how can we store the data into the warehouse without a proper layer of ETL operations?! Moreover, the data warehouse, as a storage, is nothing but a database with less keys and no normalization constraints. The key factor in data warehousing is first the ETL process and the large storage place.

Comment: So, if we ignore the storage part, let me re-formulate the question to be: What are the differences between the ETL opertions that I can do in Redshift when compared to the Glue's?

Comment: A database doesn't have to provide ETL capabilties by any means, although of course you need to have ways to get the data in. These can be as minimal as inserts, updates and deletes. ETL tools are tools that specialise in the movement of data, both the organisation, ordering and synchronising of those operations and the development of the operations that move and transform the data.

Comment: Yet SQL views and statements can accomplish many of the operations you might perform via Spark on Glue, like creating a new column based on the contents of another column or aggregating columns via predefined functions like SUM. I read the question as asking “what data modification can I do in glue that I can’t do in Redshift?”, which is my question, by the way.